# How to design xml for tables with meta information?

Tags: xml, database, datamodel

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Elementid  
DescriptionName
```

Now if there are 10 elements in this table , there is one table for each element as follows

```
PartId
PartName
```

for each part then there is table describing properties

```
propid
propName
propunit
```

in short this is a nested relation where ids are primary key but may have same values in different tables.

These tables are associated with each other with meta information and not like foreign keys or an extra column to specify the associated element for part or associated part for property.

I want to have an XML document of the data.I will need to identify which  part table is associated to which element and which property table is associated with which part. Within Xml there will be no need of  extra element as this can be identified by the attribute or meta information of the table

IS there a Data model to store this in tabular form in excel or database which is easily convertible to `xml`? what should be the design/schema for `xml` or the tables?
The main problem is attributes or meta information.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which database, but if `SqlServer` is an option, [FOR XML AUTO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188273.aspx) works by nesting each joined subelement beneath its parent, which sounds more or less is what you are after?

Comment: which database is not a restriction.All i say is if tables are linked only by metainformation (eg parent=ElementID) and how the xml will look like around it ? will it preserve that info ? can it be simplified to be used in Excel ?